# JQuery DatePicker in bPopup

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui-datepicker, bpopup

Hey I am using the datepicker of JQuery in one of my page. It works fine when I check this page separately, but when I try to open this page using bPopup the page does not display at all. When I checked the html source, the page is loading but within a class="b-ajax-wrapper" container div, and display is set to "none". When I remove the "display:none" with help of firebug, it start displaying the page. But now, the date-picker is not working. Can you please point me where I am doing some mistake.

Comment: you may not include jquery-ui.js in your html page.
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>
  <script src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.3/jquery-ui.js"></script>

Comment: You mean I should remove the jquery and jquery-ui from the popup html? Then how it will open the datepicker?

Comment: you need to include only one time for page only not again for popup .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Including both "jquery.min" and "jquery.ui" only in parent HTML page is required, not again in popup page. [Credit: @Manoj]